# WM-Factory no interface method getBackgroundExecutor()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning android development from Android_developer. while using CoroutinesWorker, I encountered a problem whilst working with Kotlin

**Logcat**

```
com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could 
not instantiate 
com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer.work.RefreshDataWorker
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at 
androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(Worker
Factory.java:96)
        at 
androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:
244)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
```

The Application class from where I instantiate workmanager.

**Application class**

```
package com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer

import android.app.Application
import androidx.work.*
import 
com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer.work.RefreshDataWorker
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import timber.log.Timber
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
```

As I have read in related posts, my worker class is a top level class and in an independent file.

**Worker class**

```
package com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer.work

import android.content.Context
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer.database.getDatabase
import com.google.samples.apps.devbyteviewer.repository.VideosRepository
import retrofit2.HttpException
import timber.log.Timber


class RefreshDataWorker(appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val database = getDatabase(applicationContext)
        val repository = VideosRepository(database)

        try {
            repository.refreshVideos()
            Timber.d("Work request for sync is run")
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            return Result.retry()
        }

        return Result.success()
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Define a work name to uniquely identify this worker.
         */
        const val WORK_NAME = "com.example.android.devbyteviewer.work.RefreshDataWorker"
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace? I would expect another section (or more) starting with "Caused by" and a nested exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem while working with WorkManager.

Pulling meaning from your post and the error message, this is very likely an **import** related issue. Check your Application dependencies.

Rather than:

```
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
```

Use:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
```

Comment: Exactly... that was the problem. I changed the dependency and it worked